# Is there a way to get Chrome's Dev Tools to show the manifest download information?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging an [offline application](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#offline), and Chrome's Dev Tools Network tab doesn't seem to show any information at all about the cache manifest download. I see the download of the main page, followed by its various resources, but there's no network entry for the manifest identified on the `html` element — not initially, and not at the end when it re-downloads it to see if it changed.

Is there some magic option to makes Dev Tools show the manifest download as well?

For example, say we have `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="m.appcache">
<head>
    <!-- ...usual head stuff... -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- ...some content... -->
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the manifest looks like:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v1
style.css
script.js
```

On the network tab, I'll see entries for `index.html`, `style.css`, and `script.js`, but none for `m.appcache`, even though I know the browser requests it (twice) when initially caching the page.

Answer (score -1):

In chrome-dev-tools the place you can check everything is the application tab. Not sure, but there might also be your m.appcache file.

Comment: I don't see anything there showing me the download of the manifest. Just current state information for the application.